# Comparison between Rust and C/C++ pointers for accessing values in a struct

Tags: c, rust

Some simple [Rust code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ff6c20950e84b07ad8c4e532fbd4ddbe&version=stable&backtrace=0):

```rust
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

fn main() {
    let p: &Point = &(Point { x: 0.3, y: 0.4 });
    // println!("{:?}" , p->x); // no sugar here for Rust
    println!("{:?}", (*p).x);
    println!("{:?}", p.x); // sugar?
    // no leak right? thanks Rust
}
```

And some similar [C code](http://codepad.org/crV2CARz)

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

typedef struct Point Point; 

struct Point {
    float x;
    float y; 
};

int main() {
    Point __tmp = { 0.3, 0.4 };
    Point* p = &__tmp;

    printf("%f\n", p->x); // C sugar for below
    printf("%f\n", (*p).x);
    // below doesn't work because p is a pointer to a point
    //printf("%f", p.x); // error: request for member 'x' in something not a structure or union
    // memory leak at this point right?
    return 0; 
}
```

It seems that `p` is a pointer to a `Point` in both pieces of code.

I want to make sure that Rust implementing `p.x` is (or can be thought of as) syntactic sugar and that I don't have a fundamental misunderstanding of what is going on.

Is this what they mean by *aliasing*? Is `p` in Rust more like an alias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p.x` is indeed sugar in a certain sense. Rust automatically dereferences any type that implements the trait [`Deref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) or [`DerefMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html)(depending on whether the context requires a mutable or immutable reference), when doing method/attribute look-up.

In your example, the reference `&Point` implements `Deref<Target=Point>`, so your `p.x` expression is expanded to `(*p).x`. Note that this only works, as long as the pointer type does not have an attribute/method named `x` of its own (which is not the case for a simple reference).

There is [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules) that goes on about the detailed rules for auto-dereferencing.